# Resampling a part of a dataframe with trades to ohlcv (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Okay so I want to do a backtest based on trade data. I want to loop trough the trade data and resample/agg an ohlcv based on this. If the length of the ohlcv is greater than the max of the parameters I would like to use the ohlcv to calculate the indicators values on it. But when I resample/agg my data I get always only one row (also later in the loop). Also I think this isn't the best way to loop trough a dataframe?

So every iteration I add a new line to the historical trades and then based on that historical trades dataframe I want to get the resampled ohlcv as output.

The csv data looks like this:

```
index,timestamp,trade_id,price,amount,taker_side_sell
10,1609688256174,359832187,33456.54,0.091,True
9,1609688256179,359832188,33460.03,0.003,False
8,1609688256179,359832189,33460.04,0.05,False
7,1609688256179,359832190,33460.66,0.029,False
6,1609688256251,359832191,33458.9,0.007,True
5,1609688256251,359832192,33458.8,0.007,True
4,1609688256251,359832193,33458.17,0.009,True
3,1609688256365,359832194,33461.89,0.001,True
2,1609688256399,359832195,33460.68,0.007,False
1,1609688256416,359832196,33460.67,0.223,True
0,1609688256458,359832197,33460.68,0.024,False
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

histTrades = pd.read_csv('data/binanceFutures/btc-usdt.csv')
histTrades = histTrades.set_index('timestamp')
histTrades.index = pd.to_datetime(histTrades.index, unit='ms')

ohlcv = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(histTrades.index)):
    df = histTrades.iloc[:i]

    ohlcv['open'] = df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('first')
    ohlcv['high'] = df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('max')
    ohlcv['low'] = df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('min')
    ohlcv['close'] = df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('last')
    ohlcv['volume'] = df.resample('1T')['amount'].agg('sum')

    if len(ohlcv) > calcMinKlines(params):
        pass
        # Calculate the indicator values
```

Comment: How would you like to select a part of a DataFrame? Since for the first iteration of your for cycle, when i is 0, 1, 2 or 3 then you are only selecting the first one, two, three or four rows of your original DataFrame. Then in this resampled df you do not enough values of your datetime rows to resample them with a 5T time interval

Comment: Yeah, but when I keep adding trade values it stays one output row

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. What exactly do you mean by "new trades"? What is the desired output for the input you provided?

Comment: @PierreD I want to backtest on this trade data. That's why I want to loop trough the dataframe of trades and add everytime a new one such so that I can calculate indicators on the new ohlcv. But the problem I'm gaving atm is that I only get 1 row of output of the ohlcv. This shouldn't be the case. Also my way of looping trough the trades isn't perfect I guess do you know a better way?

Comment: again: what is the expected output?  Oftentimes, explicit looping can be avoided (it is very slow). If you want some some of cumulative tally, there are better ways for that.

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand what the **expected output or behavior** is. Are you trying to get some sort of cumulative aggregate? Are you instead interested in aggregate by 5min, then chunk that into larger chunks (e.g. one day worth, or n chunks of 5-min each)?

Comment: For example in the loop the current df (line 10) is the first 200 lines of the historical trade dataframe. Than I want to get the ohlcv of that df as output.

Comment: And what happens when you have one more row (now 201 first rows of the `df`)? You simply want to update your `ohlcv` and calculate new indicator values? Even if the 200th and the 201st lines are in the same `'1T'` bin?

Comment: Indeed yeah, so that I exactly know when he would have placed a trade. Such that my backtesting results are more precise than a normal quick ohlcv backtest.

Comment: Please explain better *in the post* what the expected output is.

Comment: Is it `exapanding` ohlcv?

Comment: Yeah it's an expanding ohlcv. So every iteration I add a new line to the historical trades and then based on that historical trades dataframe I want to get the resampled ohlcv as output.

Comment: @zabop I've updated it.

Comment: I see you're not getting what you want, though accepting a for loop. Are you still interested in a vectorized `groupby()` with `expanding()`?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Yes, I'm.

Comment: @KobeJanssens You will need (1) `resample('1T')` your data to 1 min intervals while doing multiple aggregates on price and amount (2) chain `expanding()` with `agg()` again. Unfortunately you supplied too little data to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```py
import pandas as pd


histTrades = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

histTrades = histTrades.set_index('timestamp')
histTrades.index = pd.to_datetime(histTrades.index, unit='ms')

ohlcv_data = []

for i in range(len(histTrades.index)):
    df = histTrades.iloc[:i]

    ohlcv_data.append([(float(x) if len(x) > 0 else None)for x in [
    df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('first'),
    df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('max'),
    df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('min'),
    df.resample('1T')['price'].agg('last'),
    df.resample('1T')['amount'].agg('sum'),
    ]])

    #if len(ohlcv) > calcMinKlines(params):
    #    pass
        # Calculate the indicator values

ohlcv = pd.DataFrame(ohlcv_data,columns=['open','high','low','close','volume'])
```

```
open    high    low close   volume
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   33456.54    33456.54    33456.54    33456.54    0.091
2   33456.54    33460.03    33456.54    33460.03    0.094
3   33456.54    33460.04    33456.54    33460.04    0.144
4   33456.54    33460.66    33456.54    33460.66    0.173
5   33456.54    33460.66    33456.54    33458.90    0.180
6   33456.54    33460.66    33456.54    33458.80    0.187
7   33456.54    33460.66    33456.54    33458.17    0.196
8   33456.54    33461.89    33456.54    33461.89    0.197
9   33456.54    33461.89    33456.54    33460.68    0.204
10  33456.54    33461.89    33456.54    33460.67    0.427
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines here, it seems that the OP is about how to get a **cumulative tally** of all the data by groups of the given frequency. In the tally, each row reports the "open" (first value in the group), "high": the current maximum thus far, etc.

A much more efficient way than looping explicitly is to generate such a cumulative tally using `groupby`. It will have the same number of rows as the original `df`:

```
grb = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1T'))
hlv = grb.agg({
    'price': ['cummax', 'cummin'],
    'amount': ['cumsum', 'cumcount'],
})
hlv.columns = ['high', 'low', 'volume', 'count']

ohlcv = pd.concat([
    grb['price'].transform('first').to_frame('open'),
    hlv,
    df['price'].to_frame('latest'),
], axis=1)[['open', 'high', 'low', 'latest', 'volume', 'count']]
```

(Note that `latest` is really just the price, not `grb['price'].transform('last')` which would be the last of the entire group, introducing peek-ahead).

On the original data provided as example, we get for `ohlcv`:

```
                           open    high     low  latest  volume  count
date                                                                  
2020-12-17 00:17:13.378  89.973  89.973  89.973  89.973    10.5      0
2020-12-17 00:17:13.451  89.973  89.974  89.973  89.974    21.1      1
2020-12-17 00:17:14.088  89.973  89.974  89.936  89.936    22.2      2
2020-12-17 00:17:14.549  89.973  90.016  89.936  90.016    32.5      3
2020-12-17 00:17:14.564  89.973  90.016  89.936  90.016    44.4      4
2020-12-24 12:50:17.243  75.166  75.166  75.166  75.166     3.6      0
2020-12-24 12:50:18.224  75.166  75.171  75.166  75.171     3.8      1
2020-12-24 12:50:18.527  75.166  75.172  75.166  75.172     4.0      2
2020-12-24 12:50:18.527  75.166  75.174  75.166  75.174     4.1      3
2020-12-24 12:50:18.527  75.166  75.190  75.166  75.190     5.6      4
```

From that, you can calculate indicators (probably also all in one go) for the whole history, or some part of it.

Comment: No not really, I've posted a comment under my question with some more info. I hope it's now clear?

Comment: Not really. What you need to describe is the _expected result_. It's hard to infer it based on the code you give that, in your own words, is not working as expected.

Comment: Okay give me a second, I'm going to rewrite my code. Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: I hope it's now more clear what I expect as result? So yeah, my output must be an ohlcv based on the dataframe created in the loop so I can do some indicator calculations on the ohlcv.

Comment: Hmm this isn't really a solution for my problem because I should calculate my indicator values on the previous 1minute close values.